How to remove double quotes in control files (oracle sql developer)
I'm using below commands in control file
OPTIONS (SKIP=0)
LOAD DATA
BADFILE "Load_bad.bad"
TRUNCATE
INTO TABLE LOAD_DATA
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
TRAILING NULLCOLS
{
  "NAME" char
  "AGE" char
  "ID" char
  "REASON" char
  "INTEREST" char 
  "EXPERIENCE" char
}

I'm passing below values for the control file but values is not loaded into oracle database due to double quotes issue. How to remove double quotes and load it into the data base. can anyone share your ideas on how to handle this scenario in control file.
myname|12|11|"need to switch" to parent|"java" c|2|

Values are not loaded into the oracle database . If I remove double quotes, then data is loaded into the table but I want the control file to handle the double quotes.

If you have embedded quotes that aren't used to enclose the field, you need to escape them.

If you just want to remove them, you can use a shell command like tr -d '"' <inputfile > outputfile

But that will also remove quotes that are used to enclose a field that contains |.

Are you sure you need OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'? Do you actually use quotes to enclose fields?

And do you want to keep the quotes that are part of the values you showed - i.e. do you want the DB to have "java" c or java c? If you want to keep them, and you do need the optionally enclosed by, you would have to escape them. (And if you only need optionally enclosed for certain fields, not those two, then you can set that at field level; but that seems unlikely.)

I need db to have the value without double quotes and I'm trying to add regex for the particular column (interest and reason) but getting error. Can you let me know how to add regex in those columns.

Rather than changing the control file, fix the data by surrounding the values in double quotes and escaping the double quotes by doubling them:
myname|12|11|"""need to switch"" to parent"|"""java"" c"|2|

Alternatively, if you are not using double quotes around any of the values then modify the control file and remove:
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'


No, I can't surround data with double quotes and also I need optionally enclosed by ' " '. I want to handle the particular column interest and reason. I tried regex but getting error.

OPTIONS (SKIP=0)
LOAD DATA
BADFILE "Load_bad.bad"
TRUNCATE
INTO TABLE LOAD_DATA
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
TRAILING NULLCOLS
{
  NAME char ,
  AGE char,
  ID char,
  REASON char "REPLACE(REPLACE(:REASON , '\"', ''), '\"', '')",
  INTEREST char "REPLACE(REPLACE(:INTEREST, '\"', ''), '\"', '')", 
  EXPERIENCE char 
}


While this code may answer the question, might you please [edit] your post to add an explanation as to why/how it works as suggested by How do I write a good answer? This can help future readers understand and apply your answer. You are also more likely to get positive feedback (upvotes) when you include an explanation.  Thanks!
